# How do I remove a file from HDFS

Tags: hadoop

I am learning Hadoop and I have never worked on Unix before . So, I am facing a problem here . What I am doing is:

```
$ hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/user_name/abcd
```

now I am gonna put a ready made file with name `file.txt` in HDFS

```
$ hadoop fs -put file.txt /user/user_name/abcd
```

The file gets stored in hdfs since it shows up on running `-ls` command.

Now , I want to remove this file from HDFS . How should i do this ? What command should i use?

Answer (score 1):

If you run the command `hadoop fs -usage` you'll get a look at what commands the filesystem supports and with `hadoop fs -help` you'll get a more in-depth description of them.

For removing files the commands is simply `-rm` with `-rf` specified for recursively removing folders. Read the command descriptions and try them out.